# To use combination or simple multiplication rule?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm confused about to use combination or simple multiplication rule? Take an example as follow.

[image: an example]

The answer is following:
[image: solution to answer]

However, I use C(13,2) instead of the yellow part highlighted. But it's wrong. I wonder what's the difference between them and why I'm wrong by using C(13,2) instead of 13*12?

Comment: What is your logic behind using C(13,2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand that $\binom{13}2$ chooses two values for the chosen cards, *but does not specify which one will have $3$ and which one will have $2$*,

so you will get half the correct value by using $\binom{13}2$ instead.
You need to be careful about these tiny details.